# Pandas shift to the last column that contained a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a dataframe.

| Type | Scheduled |
| --- | --- |
| GP | 08/09/2019 |
| Blood | 09/09/2019 |
| Urine | 10/09/2019 |
| GP | 11/09/2019 |
| GP | 20/09/2019 |
| Physio | 20/09/2019 |

What I want to do is use something like shift to add another column which contains the date of the last GP Visit. So the data frame would end up looking like this:

| Type | Scheduled | Last GP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GP | 08/09/2019 | nan |
| Blood | 09/09/2019 | 08/09/2019 |
| Urine | 10/09/2019 | 08/09/2019 |
| GP | 11/09/2019 | 08/09/2019 |
| GP | 20/09/2019 | 11/09/2019 |
| Physio | 20/09/2019 | 20/09/2019 |

I can't work out how to do a shift based on a criteria. Any help is appreciated.

I've thought about doing this through a row-by-row analysis or doing a selection over to a separate dataframe and then some kind of lookup - but I feel like there is a simple solution I am missing.

Comment: `08/09/2019` in second and third row is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter only the GP values with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), then [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['Last GP']  = df['Scheduled'].where(df['Type'].eq('GP')).ffill().shift()
```

Output:

```
     Type   Scheduled     Last GP
0      GP  08/09/2019         NaN
1   Blood  09/09/2019  08/09/2019
2   Urine  10/09/2019  08/09/2019
3      GP  11/09/2019  08/09/2019
4      GP  20/09/2019  11/09/2019
5  Physio  20/09/2019  20/09/2019
```